# delete doesn't free memory sometimes

Tags: c++, heap-memory, delete-operator

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/

My Code snippet

```
...
{
    MyClass * pt;
    pt = new MyClass[10000];
    delete [] pt;
    pt = NULL;
}
{
    MyClass * pt;
    pt = new MyClass[10000];
    delete [] pt;
    pt = NULL;
}
...
```

doing the same twice

I monitored the process RES via [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/).

And I found that the first delete DO free memory, but the second delete DO NOT free memory.

why ?

=== UPDATE

```
struct MyClass
{
    static int counter;
    MyClass() {
        counter++;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        counter--;
    }
    ...
    ...
};


int MyClass::counter = 0;

...
{
    MyClass * pt;
    pt = new MyClass[10000];
    printf("delete-1  %x %d", pt, pt->counter);
    delete [] pt;
    pt = NULL;
    printf("delete-1  %x %d", pt, pt->counter);
}
{
    MyClass * pt;
    pt = new MyClass[10000];
    printf("delete-2  %x %d", pt, pt->counter);
    delete [] pt;
    pt = NULL;
    printf("delete-2  %x %d", pt, pt->counter);
}
...
```

**Output:**

delete-1  6c3c6018 10000

delete-1  0 0

delete-2  54000aa8 10000

delete-2  0 0

**implement again**(do not kill process)

delete-1  4c900958 10000

delete-1  0 0

delete-2  4c900958 10000      (this new DO NOT increase RES)

delete-2  0 0

**Result:**

memory keeps building up  :'(

only the first delete DO free memory

Comment: After you free the memory it is not guaranteed that the OS will immediately take it back.

Comment: Besides that, you may have a memory leak in your class MyClass so, that it may not release all memory which it had allocated.

Comment: Plus: To check if the objects are deleted, you could implement a static counter in your class, increment the value when the objects are created and decrement again when deleted. You will see that the counter is always 0 after the arrays have been deleted.

Comment: Stick it in an infinite loop. see if memory keeps building up or if you actually run out of memory.